# Manage 301 Redirect when moving oldsite to AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, seo, redirect, http-status-code-301

I'm migrating an old website to a Wordpress+AngularJS(with Typescript) architecture. We need to keep our SEO by migrating the old URLs to the AngularJS website.

Usually i'd do it using Redirect 301 in .htaccess but it doesn't seem to work with angular. :(

How would you do this?

Best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nervermind this question, htaccess rewrite rules worked. I think that's becaused I used to write "Redirect 301..." and now it needs "Redirect permanent ..."

Or not, but now it works. ;-)

Comment: This is the 100% correct answer. Thank you very much.